# For $\Bbb K^{n \times n}$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $\exists p[p(A)=B] \implies \exists p[p(B)=A]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $\Bbb K^{n \times n}$ matrices $A$ and $B$, is it true that if there exists a matrix polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)=B$, then there exists another matrix polynomial $p$ (not necessarily the same) such that $p(B) = A$?

#### My attempt

Let $B = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k A^k$, where $a_k \in \Bbb K$.

From the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), there exists a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ such that $p(A) = O$, so $A^m$ where $m \ge n$ can be expressed as linear combination of $\left\{ A^k \ | \ 0 \le k < n\right\}$.

So, we can express $B^m = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{mk} A^k$, where $a_{mk} \in \Bbb K$.

If $\{I, A, A^2, \cdots, A^{n-1}\}$ form a basis, then we can express a polynomial in $B$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k B^k$, as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{10} & a_{20} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)0} \\
a_{01} & a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)1} \\
a_{02} & a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{0(n-1)} & a_{1(n-1)} & a_{2(n-1)} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)(n-1)} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Since we want the polynomial to equal $A$, we would need to solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{10} & a_{20} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)0} \\
a_{01} & a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)1} \\
a_{02} & a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{0(n-1)} & a_{1(n-1)} & a_{2(n-1)} & \cdots & a_{(n-1)(n-1)} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Until now I have transformed the problem into a problem in linear algebra, but is utterly useless. Firstly, $\{A^k \ | \ 0 \le k < n\}$ may not even be linearly independent.

Comment: Another fun example to add to the mix: any nonzero nilpotent matrix $A$ satisfies $A^{n} = 0$ for some sufficiently large $n$. Then $p(X) = X^{n}$ has $p(A) = 0$, but for any polynomial $q$, $q(0) = c_{0}I_{n}$ where $c_{0}$ is the constant coefficient of $q$, and hence cannot be $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. Let
$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ and $p(X)=X^2$.
Then
$$B=p(A)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$
How can there be a polynomial with $q(B)=A$?

Answer (score 4):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, and let $p(x)=x^2$. Then $p(A) = I$, but there's no polynomial $q$ with $q(I) = A$.